# strtotime в воскресенье дает неверные значения

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Встретил непонятное явление...

Следующая строчка:

> strtotime('thursday this week midnight');

Возвращает конкретно СЕГОДНЯ, след. значения:

> 1500249600
>
> Mon, 17 Jul 2017 00:00:00

Но почему?... Как мне получить четверг 00:00 этой недели?

Comment: Не вторник, а четверг вы хотите получить. Но возвращает strtotime('thursday this week midnight'); все правильно - `1500508800`  `2017-07-20T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Нет, возвращает понедельник...: 1500249600

Answer (score 0):

```
php > echo date(DATE_ATOM,strtotime('tuesday this week midnight'));

2017-07-18T00:00:00+03:00
```

thursday- четверг а не вторник

Comment: Я опечатался. Нужен четверг, но вторник тоже.

Comment: Не важно, что писать туда. Хоть среду, вторник или пятница. Возвращает: 1500249600. Работает только воскресенье.
И такая фигня только в воскресенье происходит

Comment: Какой вывод echo date(DATE_ATOM,strtotime('tuesday this week midnight')); ?

Comment: 2017-07-17T00:00:00+00:00

Comment: а тут echo date(DATE_ATOM); ?

Comment: Есть вероятность что ето баг в твоей версии или с твоими настройками у меня он не проявляется на PHP 7.1.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2017 09:41:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies  настройки по умолчанию

Comment: + часовой пояс корректный поставьте если сервер не в utc +0 находиться

Comment: А есть вообще какая-то альтернатива ?

Comment: обновится к последней версии + написать баг репорт

Comment: А какая версия php у вас?

Comment: я написал же верху.

Comment: Можете прислать unixtime, который возвращает: strtotime( 'tuesday this week midnight') ?